# C: two-dimensional array slower then single-dimensional?

Tags: c, arrays

I thought, that if single-dimensional is implemented somehow like

```
a[i]=*(a+i),
```

so a[i][j] must be

```
*(a+i*ROWSIZE+j)
```

Am I wrong?

Read here http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/algorithm/135948/

> > Думаю, не стоит говорить о том, что одномерный массив быстрее двумерного, а так же, что статический массив константной длины быстрее динамического std::vector

Comment: Your question has a lot of assumptions and is much to vague. Could you please detail what a 2D array is for you? In the standard a 2D array is something that is declared such as `int a[3][4];` Is this what you have in mind? Or do you mean a pointer array that emulates a 2D array? What do you mean by slower?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "slower". In terms of actual access time (time needed to fetch data from memory), no those are both identical. In terms of the nanosecond or so needed to compute the offset, yes the 2D adds the smallest bit of overhead.

Answer (score 2):

If `a` is a multi-dimensional array, you're right. It's the same thing.
But the `a[i][j]` syntax can also be used to index an array of pointers, which is a different thing.

So it depends on the definition of a:

```
char a[N][M];   // Behaves as you describe
char *b[N];     // b[x][y] reads twice from memory.
```

Answer (score 1):

No, although your title doesn't seem to be connected to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, but it might be cleaner to type:
`a[i*ROWSIZE + j]` to make it clear that you're indexing into an array instead of just offsetting a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

In C assuming `a` is an array of array and `i`and `j` integers then in an expression,

```
a[i][j]
```

is equivalent to

```
*(*(a+i)+j)
```

For example given,

```
int a[ROW][COL];
```

then in an expression:

```
a[i][j] == *(*(a+i)+j) == *(a[i] + j) == *((int *) a + i * COL + j)
```

Comment: CAN BE equivalent to, but only if each a[i] is itself a reference to an array (as opposed to the case here, where it is a single block of memory).

Answer (score 0):

Actually that depends how a is declared.

There are at least two possibilities

```
int a[4][4];
```

allocates 4*4*sizeof(int) bytes and - as you point out - requires a multiplication to index.

The other option is

```
int **a;
```

which - when initialized - is a single dimensional array of pointers to other single dimensional arrays.

That is, a[i] returns a pointer to the actual row, and the added [j] returns the correct value in the row.

This does not require any multiplication to index.